# display data from database in django

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-admin, django-views

models.py

```
class Types(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True)
    title = models.CharField('Incident Type', max_length=200)
    parent_type_id = models.CharField('Parent Type', max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    is_active = models.BooleanField('Is Active', default=True)
```

The above view and form is used to add data to database and display in template with check box appear dynamically.So now i want to take these vales from database and display it in another page.For that,my views.py is

```
def what(request):
    user = request.user
    type = TypeSelectionForm(type_id)
    types = Types.objects.filter(user=user.id, parent_type_id=None).order_by('title')
    typelist = Types.objects.filter(user=user.id,parent_type_id=type_id).order_by('title')
 #   type = Types.objects.filter(parent_type_id=type_id)
    return render(request, 'incident/what.html',
        {
            'newreport_menu': True,
            'types':types,
            'typelist': typelist,
    })
```

I am trying to filter the data from database and display it in another page through the above mentioned view,buti am not sure the code i used in `What` view is correct,because it is not giving the relevent output.For e.g if the value in database is "School" it is showing the output as `[<Types: Types object>, <Types: Types object>] [<Types: Types object>, <Types: Types object>]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your problem is with the `<Types: Types object>` part, add a `__unicode__()` method to your `Types` model.

```
class Types(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True)
    title = models.CharField('Incident Type', max_length=200)
    parent_type_id = models.CharField('Parent Type', max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    is_active = models.BooleanField('Is Active', default=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title

    @property
    def parent_types(self):
        """ For accessing the parent types without introducing relationship """
        return self.objects.filter(pk=self.parent_type_id)
```

This will show the `title` of the object in the list instead of `<Types: Types object>`.

Update: I've added a property so that you can access the parent types like `types.parent_types` without changing the model.

Comment: after changing this my output looks like [<Types: Bus>, <Types: School>] [<Types: Bus>, <Types: School>].In db i am using a field parent_type_id it tells the list is parent or child.So i want to display  the child element below the parent.I am able to display the parent element,but not the child element,need assistance to display the child element

Comment: Instead of CharField for parent type id, use ForeignKey or OneToOneField, depending on your need. Then you can access the parent types directly. I think you should go through the relationship section of Django.

Comment: But a learner i can't make changes in db since it was designed already,from views code is it possible to show the child element in what view.This is only i am trying i don't know how to implement this.Please share me your idea to do this

Comment: can any one tell me how to do.It will be a great help for me

Comment: Added a method to get parent types from the object itself. Try it

Comment: Should i make any changes in views or forms for the above change in model.I written this line "typelist=Types.objects.filter(user=user.id).order_by('title')" to display the child elements,but it is showing parent element also.If i set parent_type_id=None it will dispaly only parent element and if parent_type_id=True nothing comes to display

Comment: try `parent_type_id__isnull=False`.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30736/discussion-between-user2086641-and-bibhas)

Comment: The above answer worked for me,still have some issue i am solving that.Thanks